# React js remove third party rendered html

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have below code

```
<div id="parent">
<div id="dvWeather">
{
data && (
thirdparty.renderWeatherInfo(data,"dvWeather")
)
}
<div/>
</div>
```

What it does

```
<div id="parent">
<div id="dvWeather">
<div id="mtWeather">
other stuff
</div>
<div/>
</div>
```

So it is working when it data has value, but when I update the data with state to null, it renders but the content of dvWeather does not remove.

But when I do simply this

```
<div id="parent">
<div id="dvWeather">
{
data && (
<h2>Hello</h2>
) 
}
<div/>
</div>
```

I can see when data is not null h2 is rendering, if null then blank

**Third party is using react react dom to render component in given div**

I believe this because dvWeather has been rendered by different reactjs state, so in my project state unable to remove it

What could be the possible issue and work around it

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps the third party is bugged, I find it weird that they would use `react-dom` but not `react` and provide a proper component for it. I'm not too familiar with how react works internally but I've never seen this kind of approach to append pre-rendered dom to react jsx.

Comment: @yifansong, no bro I don't this so. I believe this because dvWeather has been rendered by different reactjs state, so in my project state unable to remove it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this way

```
<div id="parent">
<div id="dvWeather">
{
data ? (
thirdparty.renderWeatherInfo(data,"dvWeather")
) : null
}
<div/>
</div>
```

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam what `data` shows in this case? can you log it to see?

Comment: nothing its simply retaining the rendered div by third party